# SPARQL: Choose one triple from multiple match?

Tags: match, sparql, rdf

I have a kind of interesting problem with SPARQL query. I am querying for a triple and I have multiple match - maybe 2. But I need the code to choose only one. It absolutely doesn't matter which one. 
For example: I am querying for a book for 5-years old and it founds 2 books in the database but I need to have only one saved in variable (doesn't matter which one). 
Is this even possible in SPARQL? Please let me know if you need any other information. Thank you all in advance for your time!
The change in input database is the last thing I want to do.

EXAMPLE:

```xml
<Book rdf:ID = 0001>
<Book.Title>Title1</Book.Title>
<Book.For>5 years old</Book.For>
<Book.Date>2000</Book.Date>
</Book>

<Book rdf:ID = 0002>
<Book.Title>Title2</Book.Title>
<Book.For>5 years old</Book.For>
<Book.Date>2005</Book.Date>
</Book>
```

```sql
Construct {?NewDatabase Example_of_book_for_5_years_old ?Title .}
Where {?Example Book.For "5 years old" .
       ?Example Book.Title ?Title .
      };
```

Both books match the Where clause but I need only one to be in the new database output. Doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Without seeing data (minimal fragment) AND SPARQL query, nobody will help you! Please add that information to your question.

Comment: And what is "10 rdfs"?

Comment: If you just want the first result of a query, you can add LIMIT 1 to your query.

Comment: I have added an example. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Properties like `Book.For` are weird. Is this an actual running SPARQL query?

Comment: Also, the `CONSTRUCT` is not valid

Comment: no it is only an example not actual query. 
I need to construct another rdf file from my input therefor I have to use construct, I guess.

Comment: You might also investigate the `SAMPLE` keyword of SPARQL 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Not considering the apparent errors in your example query, the solution is to use `SELECT` instead of `CONSTRUCT`. The former allows you to limit the number of results.</strike>

If you totally need a triple as result, you can use limited `SELECT` as a subquery

To select only one triple from a `CONSTRUCT` query you can use the `LIMIT` clause just like with `SELECT`

```sql
Construct { ?Example <urn:Book:Title> ?Title }
Where {
   ?Example <urn:Book:For> "5 years old" .
   ?Example <urn:Book:Title> ?Title .
} 
limit 1
```

This will select the first result (order undetermined).

---

And no, the judging by the [SPARQL Grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rUpdate), it is not possible to use the `LIMIT` clause with SPARQL Updates.

Comment: @ThomaszPluskiewicz Your answer is correct given the information we have so far. As a side note: I would reformulate the phrase "the solution is to use SELECT instead of CONSTRUCT". It's more the task of using SELECT inside of the query pattern of the CONSTRUCT query.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. Is it possible to use this subquery with select * also to **DELETE/INSERT/WHERE** query?
In fact I need to delete old example and put a new one instead.

Comment: @AKSW Actually, I was wrong. `LIMIT` is indeed allowed with `CONSTRUCT`. Updating answer

Comment: @EduardDindoffer I'm not sure but I don't think subqueries are allowed in `DELETE WHERE` either: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rDeleteWhere

Comment: Do you think there is any other solution to my problem since the LIMIT is not possible with SPARQL Updates?
I need to update the database with only one ?Title.

Comment: Is it possible to make LIMIT only for a subquery result? Not for the whole query? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible to LIMIT any query - also a subquery. As in the [previous version of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38952612/1).

Comment: For the Update issue, I think you should open a more specific SO question. The answer doesn't really fit in comments

Comment: Can you please explain me what is SO question and what should be there? I am new to this web, thank you. Also for the comments.

Comment: I have created another question with more info. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967938/sparql-choose-one-triple-from-multiple-match-supplementation

Comment: SO - Stack Overflow. Sorry :)