# SPARQL: Choose one triple from multiple match? Supplementation

Tags: limit, sparql

I have a query for updating my RDF database. The problem is that `?Terminal2` block of query is returning two different `?Terminal2`'s (both match the query) and that is making my code useless. I would need to somehow limit it for only one `?Terminal2` - doesn't matter which one. When I put this code to TopBraid, I get only one line in output so the `LIMIT` is working for the whole code not just for that subquery. Do you have any idea how to make my code working? There were some ideas about using `SAMPLE`. (I had opened [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950644/sparql-choose-one-triple-from-multiple-match?noredirect=1#comment65267413_38950644).)

```
DELETE 
{ 
  ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
}
INSERT 
{ 
  ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2_new .
  ?Terminal2 blb:used ?used .
  ?Terminal3 blb:used ?used .
  ?T2 blb:used ?used .
}

WHERE
{ 
  ?Terminal1 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
  ?Terminal1 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T2" .
  ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
  ?Terminal1 blb:IdentifiedObject.description ?desc .

  FILTER(?desc != "Evo") .    
  BIND(("Used") as ?used) .

  {
    select * WHERE 
    {
      ?Terminal2 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
      ?Terminal2 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T2" .
      ?Terminal2 blb:IdentifiedObject.description "Evo" .
      ?Terminal2 blb:Terminal.ConductingEquipment ?Parent .
      ?Terminal2 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
    }
    limit 1
  }

  ?Terminal3 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
  ?Terminal3 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T1" .
  ?Terminal3 blb:IdentifiedObject.description "Evo" .
  ?Terminal3 blb:Terminal.ConductingEquipment ?Parent .
  ?Terminal3 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2_new .

  OPTIONAL 
  {
    ?T2 rdf:type blb:ConnectivityNode .
  }
}
```

Thanks for help!

This code below works (exactly as I need) in TopBraid (with `SELECT *`), but not as `DELETE`/`INSERT` query. The error is 
`Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " <INTEGER> "1 "" at line 1, column 1040.`

```
DELETE 
{ 
  ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
}
INSERT 
{ 
  ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2_new .
  ?Terminal2 blb:used ?used .
  ?Terminal3 blb:used ?used .
  ?T2 blb:used ?used .
}
WHERE  
{       ?Terminal1 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
        ?Terminal1 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T2" .
        ?Terminal1 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
        ?Terminal1 blb:IdentifiedObject.description ?desc .
        FILTER(?desc != "EVO") .
        BIND(("Used") as ?used) .

    {
        select ?Terminal2 (SAMPLE(?Parent2) AS ?Parent ) WHERE 
       {
        ?Terminal2 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
        ?Terminal2 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T2" .
        ?Terminal2 blb:IdentifiedObject.description "EVO" .
        ?Terminal2 blb:Terminal.ConductingEquipment ?Parent2 .
        ?Terminal2 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2 .
       }
        GROUP BY ?Terminal2
        LIMIT 1
    }
        ?Terminal3 rdf:type blb:Terminal .
        ?Terminal3 blb:IdentifiedObject.name "T1" .
        ?Terminal3 blb:IdentifiedObject.description "EVO" .
        ?Terminal3 blb:Terminal.ConductingEquipment ?Parent .
        ?Terminal3 blb:Terminal.ConnectivityNode ?T2_new .

        OPTIONAL{?T2 rdf:type blb:ConnectivityNode .}
}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, your sub-SELECT returns two results?

Comment: Yes. Two results are matching ?Terminal2 subquery. I need the whole query to work with only 1 result of ?Terminal2 subquery, no matter which one. I am very sorry I cant explain it better. Please, ask if there is anything unclear.

Comment: But then it's a bug, that query is correct and w.r.t. SPARQL standard returns at most one result. Can you try it with another SPARQL engine, like Jena or similar? And maybe also share a minimal dataset.

Comment: By the way, terminal2 and terminal3 must have the same ConductingEquipment, right? and terminal1 and terminal2 the same ConnectivityNode? Just to understand your query

Comment: What happens if you run the sub-SELECT in a separate SELECT query? I mean  `SELECT * WHERE { {SELECT * WHERE {...} LIMIT 1} }`

Comment: I am running Jena 2.6.4. Yes you understand the query correctly. There is an element "EVO" which needs to be eliminated from the database but in order to not loose connections I have to change everything that is connected to its left terminal to its right terminal. Then I will mark this element "EVO" with "Used" sign and delete it in later step. The problem is when there are two of "EVO" elements connected to one connectivity node. Then I need to choose only one way to go. Doesn't matter which one. I will add a minimal dataset in a while. Thanks for comments.

Comment: Where can I upload the minimal dataset? It is too long for a comment.

Comment: Jena 2.6.4 is extremely old (5.5 years) - I would strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent version.  Use either 3.1.0 or if you need to stick with Java 7 use 2.13.0

Comment: @RobV what is the biggest benefit? Can it be the reason my code is not running? I am completely new to this environment. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @AKSW I have updated the code in my question and it is working but not with DELETE/INSERT query structure. Is there any workaround in your opinion? Thank you.

Comment: The biggest benefit is that you get 5.5 years of improvements, bug fixes, new features and performance enhancements.

Comment: @EduardDindoffer Can you please update your question such that it contains the current SPARQL DELETE/INSERT query that leads to an Exception?

Comment: @AKSW I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: For me this query can be parsed without any exception - Apache Jena 2.13.x. Can you please use the latest version from 2.13 release?

Comment: I checked it again and it is not working since the subquery is evaluated first. I get always the same ?Terminal2. I think I have to change the query logic completely. Thank you all for trying to help!